# knockout.js: the If and foreach bindings, checking for truth value on observable array

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the little details of using the if and for each bindings. I'm hoping someone can point out something obvious to me.

I have an empty array, using `Boolean(observableArray().length)` I get false. That is no problem. However I can't get this kind of expression to work in an `if` binding.

If I start with an empty array and push data to it, I'm not getting the html element to appear. If I start with a filled array, the  element appears but is removed when I remove the data and then won't reappear(?) when I add the data back.

Here is a fiddle with the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/Robinrich/rmn7afpm/25/

Here is the code:

```
function dataForTest(data) {
  var that = this;
  that.data = data;
}

function testViewModel() {
  var that = this;

  //Truth testing array.
  that.truthTest = ko.observableArray([new dataForTest("data")]);
  that.truFal = ko.observable(Boolean(that.truthTest().length));

  //Data to push and remove.
  var data = new dataForTest("data");

  that.pushData = function() {
    that.truthTest().push(data);
    that.truFal(Boolean(that.truthTest().length));
  }

  that.removeData = function() {
    that.truthTest([]);
    that.truFal(Boolean(that.truthTest().length));
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new testViewModel());
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<h1> Testing array.length truthiness.</h1>
<button data-bind="click: pushData">Push Data</button>
<button data-bind="click: removeData">Remove Data</button>
<div data-bind="if: truthTest().length">
  <p>Data exists.</p>
  <ul data-bind="foreach: truthTest">
    <li><span data-bind="text: data"></span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<p> There is data: <span data-bind="text: truFal()"></span>
</p>
```

I start with 1 instance of data and its fine. The data appears. This is what I expect, the expression `if: truthTest().length` evaluates true and the element renders. So why doesn't it re-render after it has evaluated to false? Am I emptying and adding to the array improperly? I think this is where the problem is because if I start with a filled array and continue to push data, the `<ul>` isn't updating, but the truth value of `Boolean(truthTest().length)` is.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `that.truthTest().push(data);` to `that.truthTest.push(data);`

Check [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/cdbb4v2f/)